# Authentication and authorization with multiple middlewares in asp.net core 3.1+

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, authorization, openid-connect

I'm trying to configure authentication and authorization middleware in an asp.net core 3.1 API project to be able to authorize users from:

- on-premise IdentityServer4 (IDS) and
- AD managed in Azure (AAD).

I'm planning to use JWT bearer tokens in both cases to call the API endpoints.

The IDS users are authenticated in a mobile app against the IDS.
The AAD users are authenticated in an admin SPA against the AAD.
The web api has separate public endpoints for IDS users and management endpoints for AAD users.

There are lots of working samples about how to configure web APIs for IDS and AAD separately, but not together.

Does anyone have an example with how this should be done?

Is it even possible to use different auth schemes (e.g `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`) for an incoming JWT bearer token?

Any directions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple AddOpenIdConnect schemes, one for AzureAD and one for IdentityServer and then let the user challenge one of them, like:

```
await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("identityserver");
```

or

```
await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("azuread");
```

JwtBearerDefaults only deals with processing incoming tokens and creating a user out of it.

But each JwtBearer API's likes to have one "authority"-server (not multiple). So you might need to to add multiple AddJwtBearer(one for each server).

Or you use IdentityServer as your main authorization provider and then login to Azure through IdentityServer. So your internal servers only needs to know about IdentityServer and its tokens.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look. brb :)